# Verb: Cover the cost or get a higher return?

Tags: word-request, verbs

I wonder if there exists a verb that indicates covering the costs or getting a higher return. It would be either a transitive verb preceding "investment" or "cost", or simply an intransitive verb.

For instance, in [this thread](https://twitter.com/draecomino/status/1362051082273386500?s=20) I see that the cost of training a model would be extremely expensive. I know big giants like Google and Facebook can afford that and can "earn back" the investment since they have large-scale deployments and massive users. But for most companies, it would be highly risky since they cannot get a net positive ROI basing on their market size.

I can use ["回本"](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%9B%9E%E6%9C%AC/22217394?fr=aladdin) in Chinese to express that the return covers the cost(and most times implying that the return would be greater than the cost). For instance, "我回本了"(literally, *I have [the verb] [the investment]*), "这钱能回本吗？(literally, *can this money [the verb]?*)".

I know there maybe not exist such a verb, then how do you express that in a native way?

Comment: Do you have any example sentences? That would be helpful in finding you something appropriate.

Comment: @AIQ For example, "I *** the investment/cost" or "Can A *** the investment or cost?" or "Can A ***?" A stands for an entity or the investment(in the last example).

Comment: Google Translate suggests "pay back", which seems like a pretty good choice:  https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=%E5%9B%9E%E6%9C%AC&op=translate

Answer (score 1):

If you invest and then subsequently earn enough to pay back that investment you have reached the break-even point or you have broken even. Once you have done that any further earnings are profit (after deducting production costs).